# How to position title to left and logo to right on Android ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm very new to Android development, so I really need a helping hand. I would like to add a custom ActionBar to my app. I would like to have the title displayed on the left side, and the logo of my app on the right side. I have searched the net for solutions, but all I could reach is to have the title positioned to the left OR the logo positioned to the right, but could not get both be displayed. Anyone can help me how can I reach the desired display? I know Google suggest to have to logo on the left side, but this time I need to "overwrite" this "rule".

Comment: You could put `TextView` and `ImageView` inside `Toolbar` xml on desired positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this following code for custom `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="6dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tittle here"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>




        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Output:**

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem, I just had to position my ListView below the toolbar, otherwise it was on top of the first item. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Yupi said, [toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) is an extended class of ViewGroup. So you can use just like LinearLayout to contain your custom.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:elevation="6dp">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="300dp">

             <!-  Your TextView / ImageView -->

        </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```